# hide UISearchBar below UINavigationBar after cancelButton was called

Tags: iphone, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller, cancel-button

I'm typically using `[self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,40)];` in order to hide the UISearchBar (that I set as header of the tableView) below the navigationBar. Everything works well in viewDidLoad: the searchBar is below the navigationBar when the view is loaded. Then I put the same line of code

```
[self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,40)]
```

in

```
- (void)searchDisplayControllerWillEndSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller
```

but it does anything: the searchBar remain visible when cancel Button is clicked.
What's wrong?

Answer (score 4):

The following method should do it:

```
-(void)searchDisplayControllerDidEndSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller{
    [self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,40)];    
}
```

Comment: make sure you add UISearchBar to the tableview. then only contentOffset concept will work.

Answer (score 1):

Is the method below being called from the main thread?

```
- (void)searchDisplayControllerWillEndSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller
```

You can check like this:

```
if ([NSThread isMainThread]) {
    NSLog(@"Yes it is the main thread.");
}
```

Otherwise, any view changes will not register on screen. If you must modify the view from a separate thread you can use this:

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(XXX) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```

I'm not sure if that's your issue, but it's where I'd start to look.